# Serialize nested Pydantic model as a single value

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary, pydantic

Let's say I have this `Id` class:

```py
class Id(BaseModel):
    value: Optional[str]
```

The main point in this class, is that it serialized into **one singular** value (mostly string).

And I use that model inside another model:

```py
class Item(BaseModel):
    id: Id
    name: str
```

Everything works alright here. But when I generate the `dict` of an `Item` instance, it is generated like this:

```py
{'id': {'value': 'my id here'}, 'name': 'my name'}
```

Same thing for the `json` generation.

I want it to be generated like this:

```py
{'id': 'my id here', 'name': 'my name'}
```

And still keep the same models. How do I do that?

Comment: You can [specify](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/#modeljson) a custom way to serialise fields of a model based on their type.

Comment: But it's only when I serialize it to `json` string. What if I want it to a `dict`?

Comment: Also, this solution doesn't solve `decoding`, how I define how it `decodes` the fields I define how to [`encode`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/exporting_models/#json_encoders)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: The hacky way

If you don't mind overriding protected methods, you can hook into `BaseModel._iter`. It is currently used inside both the [`dict`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.5/pydantic/main.py#L428) and the [`json`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.5/pydantic/main.py#L462) method to go through the field values:

```py
from collections.abc import Generator, Mapping, Set
from typing import Any, Optional, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Id(BaseModel):
    value: Optional[str]

class Item(BaseModel):
    id: Id
    name: str

    def _iter(
        self,
        to_dict: bool = False,
        by_alias: bool = False,
        include: Union[Set[Union[int, str]], Mapping[Union[int, str], Any], None] = None,
        exclude: Union[Set[Union[int, str]], Mapping[Union[int, str], Any], None] = None,
        exclude_unset: bool = False,
        exclude_defaults: bool = False,
        exclude_none: bool = False,
    ) -> Generator[tuple[str, Any], None, None]:
        field_value_iterator = super()._iter(
            to_dict=to_dict,
            by_alias=by_alias,
            include=include,
            exclude=exclude,
            exclude_unset=exclude_unset,
            exclude_defaults=exclude_defaults,
            exclude_none=exclude_none,
        )
        for name, obj in field_value_iterator:
            if name == "id":
                if isinstance(obj, Id):
                    yield name, obj.value
                elif isinstance(obj, dict):
                    yield name, obj["value"]
                else:
                    raise RuntimeError("should be unreachable")
            else:
                yield name, obj
```

But for reasons that should be obvious, I don't recommend it. Non-public methods should be considered implementation details and if you meddle with them, you should expect things to break with every new update. But if you know what you are doing, this might be an option.

Demo:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    item = Item.parse_obj({"id": {"value": "my id here"}, "name": "my name"})
    print(item)
    print(item.dict())
    print(item.json())
```

Output:

```
id=Id(value='my id here') name='my name'
```

```py
{'id': 'my id here', 'name': 'my name'}
```

```json
{"id": "my id here", "name": "my name"}
```

I suppose you could just override both `dict` and `json` separately, but that would be even worse in my opinion. Aside from duplicating code, `json` would require you to either parse and re-dump the JSON string or again meddle with the protected `_iter` method.

The entire premise of hacking serialization this way seems very questionable to me. The model should represent the schema you *actually* want. What is the point of defining the `id` field as being of the type `Id`, if it serializes as something different?

Models should behave "as advertised" in my opinion and configuring `dict` and `json` representations to change field types and values breaks this fundamental contract. Thus, I would propose an alternative.

---

### Option 2: The reasonable way

Define a new model to parse `Item` instances into the schema you *actually* need using a custom [`pre=True` validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators):

```py
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Id(BaseModel):
    value: Optional[str]


class Item(BaseModel):
    id: Id
    name: str


class FlatItem(BaseModel):
    id: Optional[str]
    name: str

    @validator("id", pre=True)
    def get_model_value(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, Id):
            return v.value
        return v

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

If you can, avoid duplication (I assume the actual models will have more fields) by defining a base class for both `Item` variants:

```py
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Id(BaseModel):
    value: Optional[str]


class _BaseItem(BaseModel):
    name: str


class Item(_BaseItem):
    id: Id


class FlatItem(_BaseItem):
    id: Optional[str]

    @validator("id", pre=True)
    def get_model_value(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, Id):
            return v.value
        return v

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Demo:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    item = Item.parse_obj({"id": {"value": "my id here"}, "name": "my name"})
    ...
    flat_item = FlatItem.from_orm(item)
    print(flat_item)
    print(flat_item.dict())
    print(flat_item.json())
```

Output:

```
name='my name' id='my id here'
```

```py
{'name': 'my name', 'id': 'my id here'}
```

```json
{"name": "my name", "id": "my id here"}
```

Here the actual `id` data on `FlatItem` is just the string and not the entire `Id` instance.

---

### PS

If the `value` field is the *only* required field on your `Id` model, the process is reversible using the same approach with a custom validator:

```py
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator


class Id(BaseModel):
    value: Optional[str]


class _BaseItem(BaseModel):
    name: str


class Item(_BaseItem):
    id: Id

    @validator("id", pre=True)
    def str_to_id_object(cls, v: object) -> object:
        if isinstance(v, str):
            return Id(value=v)
        return v

...
```

Demo:

```py
json_data = '{"name": "my name", "id": "my id here"}'
obj = Item.parse_raw(json_data)
print(obj)  # name='my name' id=Id(value='my id here')
```

Comment: This is a really good answer. But, what I do if I want to convert `FlatItem` to `Item`?

Comment: What do you mean? I assumed `Id` has more fields than just `value`. If that is the case, conversion works only one way because you obviously loose information by discarding all other fields, when you turn an `Id` object into just a string. Also, that was not part of your initial question. You said you wanted to turn your existing models into dictionaries and JSON string in a certain way, not that you wanted the process to be reversible. That requires a bunch of additional assumptions that you did not provide.

Comment: I said that Id is converted into singular value. In this case, just the value field. So what if I want to convert it the other way around.
So:
`{"name": "my name", "id": "my id here"}`
Would be converted to `Item` object.

Comment: @AvihaiShalom I added a section to my answer to show how you could de-serialize a JSON string like the one you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed and understandable answer.
If I want to change the serialization and de-serialization of the model, I guess that I need to use 2 models with the `@validator` decorator.